# Jenkins LocalHost: Unable to Create COM Object

Tags: jenkins, localhost, qtp

Trying to invoke a QTP and a macro via jenkins.
Made a call in the Jenkins Job for the same. But getting error that 
"cant create Quictest.Application object."
However, when Clicking on vbs file, it works fine.

Comment: How are you invoking QTP from Jenkins. Need more details to give any solution.

Comment: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://www.google.com"

Comment: I am trying to access automation object model for QTP, in a vbs file.

Comment: above example is for Invoking IE by same method, but here same messages is displayed, that unable to create comobject for IE